# I am having too many yellow lines in my flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need to write error-free, clean code for my flutter app.

In a stateless widget, if I delete const from the constructor, a yellow line error appears as seen below:

> This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: PerytonDropDown.selected

I don't know how to deal with it. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I edit my question please check

Comment: You need either to remove `@immutable` annotation from those classes or make all properties `final`.

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple, just initialize your variable with `final`.

Like Below :

```
final String text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Meterial widget instead of Scaffold